# Filling a gap in double-active free-swing double-doors

Tags: doors

I have a set of double doors into a water closet (within a larger bathroom) which we want to keep as free swinging with each door being able to swing past each other.

The upper hinge is mounted into the door frame, so it's not really possible to offset the doors from the jamb to reduce the center gap.

A (very large) astragal would close the gap, but then would let the doors get into an aesthetically unpleasing state depending on which one returned to center first.

Is the best I can achieve here something like 3/4" weather stripping adhered to each door? Or is there something like an astragal, but soft, so it occupies the space without providing a rigid barrier?

"move the doors" and "buy wider doors" are both considered out of scope.

The total gap is currently 1 7/8".  Getting it under 1/4" seems like it would be much more aesthetically pleasing.

[image: Double doors with a large gap]

[image: Whole door view]

[image: Top mount]

[image: Bottom mount]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two soft astragals and make them overlap slightly.

If the sweep (soft part) is very thin, the misalignment of the closed doors will be almost unnoticeable.<sup>1</sup> You'll have to shop around to see what you can get. A wider sweep is better because it will flex more. I think the "T" style is more attractive than the draft-stop style. You might have to add some wooden strips to the door edges to narrow the gap slightly.

Here in cross section are some suggested arrangements:

[image: I'm sorry I just like to draw]

---

1. Well, of course *you* will notice it because you know it is there. No one else will notice, trust me.

Comment: The second picture is what I envisioned, but couldn’t find a likely product for any name I tried in a search. Any chance you could scare one up?

Comment: https://www.doorcloser.com/acatalog/18100-96---8ft.--Nylon-Brush-Astragal-Weatherstrip-18101_96.html#SID=334 -- several varieties, the longer bristles cost more.

Comment: https://www.doorwaysplus.com/pemko-brush-astragal-18041cnb-aluminum.html or https://www.tmsoundproofing.com/Double-Astragal-with-Neoprene-Lip-Seal.html

Comment: +1, nice illustrations. Another option would be to just utilize the "wooden strip" method to narrow the gap as much as possible. You could put strips on the hinge sides and scoot the doors closer together.

Comment: A reason I wanted to see the hinge side...you could move the doors closer together with a piece of trim to match or accent the framing, drill a new hole in the top of the frame and re-install the doors. Then if you still need a strip to go between the doors, you have more options in a weather strip type.

Comment: Adding to the frame will keep the doors proportional on both sides. I am the kind of person that would notice an extra strip of wood on one side and not on the other, my wife hates how I notice even the smallest things. Therefore I suggest adding the strip to make the frame smaller and moving the doors closer.

Comment: @Jeff Cates: Well, it's up to bartonjs, but I am the kind of person that would notice an extra hole in the lintel next to the one with the hinge pin in it.

Comment: Lol, a hole can be plugged and painted!!